# Función JavaScript para refrescar un div

Tags: javascript

Hola no se mucho de JavaScript y estoy buscando una función con la que pueda refrescar un div.

Seguramente la que estoy usando esta bastante mal y me vendría bien algo de ayuda. De antemano gracias!

Acá mi código.

Esta la tabla que quiero refrescar y posteriormente el script.
Pd: no se si el hecho de tener varios php dentro de la tabla afecte lo que quiero hacer.

```
<div id="mostrardatos" class="table-responsive table-bordered" style="border-radius: 20px;width: auto;background-size: auto;height: auto;">
    <a href="javascript:abrir()"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  style="background-color: #0e0391;">Editar</button></a>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr style="border-style: hidden;height: 48px;">
                <th style="border-style: hidden;width: 16px;"></th>
                <th style="width: 852px;background-size: auto;height: 48px;" colspan="7"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr height: 27px;>
                <td style="border-style: hidden;"></td>
                <td class="text-justify" style="border-radius: 20px;padding-right: 31px;width: 193px;padding-bottom: 12px;background-image: url(&quot;assets/img/guia1.jpg&quot;);background-repeat: round;height: 39px;max-height: 39px;" rowspan="4"></td>
                <td rowspan="6" style="border-style: hidden;"></td>
                <td colspan="7" style="font-size: 20px;"><strong><?php session_start();$varsesion = $_SESSION['correo'];include("abrir_conexion.php"); $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE correo = '$varsesion'"); $consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados);    echo $consulta['nombre'].'&nbsp;'.$consulta['apellido1'].'&nbsp;'.$consulta['apellido2']?></strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 48px;border-style: hidden;">
                <td></td>"
                <td style="border-style: hidden;">******</td>
                <td colspan="7">(32) </td>
            </tr>"
            <tr>"
                "<td style="border-style: hidden;"></td>
                "<td><strong>idiomas</strong></td>
                "<td><strong>lugar</strong></td>
                "<td><strong>numero</strong></td>
            </tr>"
            <tr style="border-style: hidden;">
                <td></td>
                <td><?php session_start();$varsesion = $_SESSION['correo'];include("abrir_conexion.php"); $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE correo = '$varsesion'"); $consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados);    echo $consulta['idioma'].'&nbsp;'.$consulta['idioma2'].'&nbsp;'.$consulta['idioma3']?></td>
                <td><?php session_start();$varsesion = $_SESSION['correo'];include("abrir_conexion.php"); $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE correo = '$varsesion'"); $consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados);    echo $consulta['ubicacion']?></td>
                <td>1.000</td>
            </tr>"
            <tr style="border-style: hidden;">
                <td style="border-style: hidden;"></td>
                <td style="font-size: 20px;padding: 0px;"><br><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<?php session_start();$varsesion = $_SESSION['correo'];include("abrir_conexion.php"); $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE correo = '$varsesion'"); $consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados);    echo $consulta['valor']?></strong><br><br></td>
                <td class="text-justify" rowspan="2" colspan="5"><?php session_start();$varsesion = $_SESSION['correo'];include("abrir_conexion.php"); $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE correo = '$varsesion'"); $consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados);    echo $consulta['descripcion']?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border-style: hidden;">
                <td style="border-style: hidden;"></td>
                <td style="padding-left: 36px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>       
    setInterval(imprimir, 2000);
    function imprimr() {        
        document.show("mostrardatos")
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Buscas que los datos de la tabla se actualicen cada cierto tiempo o qué quieres hacer cuando dices "Actualizar un div"?

Comment: Hola Fabian! Si, es eso lo que busco, que los datos se actualicen cada cierto tiempo. Pero creo que lo estoy haciendo mal, realmente no se cual es la forma correcta.
Creo que si se refresca el div por ende los datos de la tabla también

Comment: Desde Js puedes crear una función y usar el `setTimeout` o el `setInterval` para llamarla cada cierto tiempo, pero esa función debe ejecutar algo que dispare la consulta de los datos nuevamente, tienes el método que hace la consulta de todos los datos con los que llenas la tabla en `PHP` o en `JavaScript`?

Comment: Esa es mi otra duda. En cada campo de la tabla hago un query para llamar el dato que quiero obtener.  Mas abajo hago la función con setInterval de la que hablas, pero no se si esta bien hecha. en ella llamo a mostrardatos, que es el id del div que quiero actualizar cada x tiempo

Comment: Intenta llenando la tabla usando este ejemplo: https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/PHP/1490669-Crear-y-llenar-tabla-con-consulta-a-base-de-datos.html , ahí ellos usan un solo query para obtener datos de una base de datos, que es lo más optimo.
Luego puedes intentar creando una función que haga esa misma consulta y llenado de datos en la tabla y lo llamas desde un botón, y puedes hacer por `JavaScript` o  por `PHP` se ejecute el evento Click en ese botón cada cierto tiempo para que se actualice la información

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré la forma de hacerlo por si alguien en el futuro necesita lo mismo.
Lo solucione trabajando con JQuery y añadiendo esta función:

```
<script>

function updateDiv()
{ 
    $( "#mostrardatos" ).load(window.location.href + " #mostrardatos" );
}
    </script>
```